# What is inside an I2C controller?

Tags: i2c

I am currently using the PCA6416A (GPIO expander with I²C interface) in a project. Here is the block diagram of this chip:
[image]

For some safety reasons, I need to know and understand what is happening inside what is called "I²C-BUS CONTROL" on the block diagram.
What is its use? How does it work? What is the hardware inside? Currently, I think it is managing the protocol (check the ACK, the address) and I am seeing it as a kind of CPU but I am not sure. If it is something like a CPU, I need to know if it has some internal memory and its capacity.
So to sum up, I would need a kind of datasheet for only this component.

The only thing I found is this website: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683711/22-3/i2c-controller-block-diagram-and-system.html.
However, it does not go into too much details and I am not sure if it applies to every kind of I²C interface.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: _"For some safety reasons"_ Please elaborate.

Comment: I do not see the point of elaborating that and furthermore I am not sure I can because of the confidentiality of the project. I just want to know what is inside the component and correct me if I am wrong but I do not think knowing more about the project has anything to do about this question.

Comment: I don't expect you to go into commercial details as to why, but there are many reasons why one would like to investigate it. For example, if you are building a satellite, you'd want to know about any memory structure used and if it's susceptible to latch-up. If you're making a medical device, you'd want to know in what modes it fails and how it can be detected.

Comment: Another thing is, will the words "I2C" and "safety" fit into same project. If you are worried about how an I2C IO expander will work in regards of safety, perhaps I2C is the wrong bus, especially if it is taken outside from a single PCB, or outside a single metal box of PCBs.

Comment: Let us say a safe CPU is sending a signature through this GPIO Expander. What I want to know is if it is possible for this device to keep in memory the entirety of the signature ?
The registers that are being used ofr I/O ports are not large enough which leaves only this component. Bus as Justme said, I think I need to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: @MaxenceV What signature? Why would some signature be sent to this device, what would it do with it? The safe CPU does not matter if you are just communicating with an I2C expander. The communication over I2C is public and can be sniffed, logged and analyzed, replicated, etc. You can even remove the expander and have a simulator for it. Your safe CPU can't know if it is talking to a real or simulated IO expander. So whatever you are worried about and why seem weird. It's just an IO expander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a piece of logic on a silicon, which implements a state machine for I2C protocol handling.

Sometimes IO expanders like this are just pre-programmed MCUs that use the MCU I2C  hardware peripheral in software or simply implement everything in software.

If you really must know for safety reasons how the chip works, ask the manufacturer. The manufacturer may help you or then manufacturer may say that your application is safety critical and if the part is not rated for safety critical applications then you should not use it.